# Response 400 from native native daemon Android with NativeDaemonConnectorException

Tags: crypt

What can be the reason for failure for below commands ?

```
CRYPT COMMAND: SND -> {3 cryptfs prepare_user_storage ! 0 0 2}
Preparing: /data/system_ce/0
Preparing: /data/misc_ce/0
Preparing: /data/media/0
Preparing: /data/data
Failed to get encryption policy for /data/system_ce/0: No such file or directory
Failed to set policy on: /data/system_ce/0
CRYPT COMMAND : RCV <- {400 3 Command failed}
```

I need to understand why it receives 400 and what can be root cause or solution to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

400 response you get it since you dont find policy for data/system_ce/0 because symlink encryption was broken and was not successful to create under encrypted folder for data/system_ce/0 hence results in failure